# Freeform form:action killing freeform

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am including a `form:action=""` parameter in my Freeform tag that runs a script. The script runs correctly, but the Freeform submission doesn't get saved to the database or emailed. Am I missing a step?

Comment: can you post the code of your form?

Comment: Does the form save the submission without the form:action param?

Answer (score 0):

form:action must point to a page that runs the index.php.
If you want to run an additional script, try using the form:onsubmit parameter.
http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#form_attribute_name